# Android Studio Chaquopy toast message

Tags: python, android, android-studio, chaquopy

I am trying to use Python in Android Studio. So, I used Chaquopy for that.

But there is a problem in Chaquopy that when I am running my app, everything is working fine but at the start of the app, it is showing a toast message that I don't want to show in my app.

The message says "This app was built with an unlicensed copy of Chaquopy. Public distribution is prohibited".

This is a screenshot of the toast message shown in the app.

[image: This is the screenshot of the toast message]

How can I hide this toast message?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can get a license by following the instructions at https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/license/.